# Are memory limit protection checks only performed under user mode?

Tags: memory, operating-system

I've tried finding information about this but can't seem to find any. Any ideas whether this is true or not?

Answer (score 0):

For 80x86; segment limit checks are done whenever the CPU is not running 64-bit code.

This includes when the CPU is in (32-bit or 16-bit) supervisor mode (CPL=0, kernel code), even if segmentation is "disabled as much as possible" (by setting all segments to "base = 0, limit = 4 GiB") because it's still possible to break the maximum limit (e.g. access 4 bytes starting at offset 0xFFFFFFFF).

It also includes when the CPU is in real mode (where there is no privilege levels but all code runs as if it is CPL=0). E.g. in real mode `mov ax,[0xFFFF]` will cause a general protection fault due to exceeding the 64 KiB segment limit.

For any other interpretations of "memory limit protection checks" (e.g. for other architectures that aren't 80x86), I don't know.